# how to make partition read and write instead of read-only?

Tags: read-only

I recently installed ubuntu on my labtop (I used windows before) and a the partition that had all my data and files previously on windows is now set to read only in linux , how can I change that ?

Comment: Do you get any messages wen mounting the partition? Or do `dmesg` or the logfile /var/log/messages say something about the partition just after mouting ?

Comment: looks like the partition is locked by the Windows fast startup feature. if you have still  a windows partiton with dual-boot, simply boot into Windows and shutdown it with `shutdown /P`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to edit your `/etc/fstab`, so you can set the permissions you need on your partition and also have it automounted in a specified mount point. This mount point has to be created before editing `/etc/fstab`. Create it using

```
sudo mkdir <mount_point>
```

- `<mount_point>` is usually a directory inside `/media`. I use `/media/Data` as my `<mount_point>`. You may want to use `/media/OS` (instead of Data and OS you can use any name you wish).

Then, you need to get your partition's UUID and type. To do that, run

```
sudo blkid
```

After determining which is your desired partition, edit `/etc/fstab`:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

At the end of the file add the following (since you were using Windows, I suppose that your partition's type is "ntfs"):

```
UUID=<your_partition's_UUID> <mount_point> ntfs-3g  defaults,nls=utf8,fmask=117,dmask=007,uid=1000,windows_names 0 0
```

- `<your_partition's_UUID>` is the UUID you got from `blkid`.
- `<mount_point>` is the mount point you created before.
- `ntfs-3g` is your partition's file system type (I supposed ntfs; if it is of another type it must be specified accordingly)
- the rest of the options set the permissions on the partition. The ones I used above give you permission to read and write to your partition and also remove the executable permission from all files of it.

Save your changes using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, close nano using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and restart your laptop for the changes to take effect.

The above settings work really well for me. However, if you need something different or you need more details about `fstab`, check this [fstab wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab).

Comment: Your answer misses the most important point, already commented: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164940/how-to-make-partition-read-and-write-instead-of-read-only#comment1941958_1164940 . Typically any NTFS partition is mounted RW without needing to edit fstab.

Comment: Yes, but as the question is stated, it is implied that the OP was using Windows in the past and that he has now replaced them with Ubuntu (OP's phrases: " (I used windows before)" and "previously on windows").

Comment: Maybe you're right but in that case I doubt that explicitly mounting it will change anything, assuming the Fast Startup hasn't been disable before installing Ubuntu. I don't know because I actually disable it routinely in any dual-boot.

Comment: I'm not sure either since I also disable it. I suppose that the OP will enlighten us.

Comment: didn't work. still read only

Comment: Do you have Windows installed on your computer or have you replaced them with Ubuntu?